# Entity Framework Code-First - Define the key for this EntityType

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

Hi I'm planning to test EF Code First in one of my project. This is what I want actually. 
I have three tables and the structure is as follows

```
public partial class App_user
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string email_address { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }
        public int user_type { get; set; }
        public List<Role> Roles { get; set; }
    }

public partial class Role
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
public partial class User_role
    {
        public int user_id { get; set; }
        public int role_id { get; set; }
        public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
        public virtual App_user App_user { get; set; }
    }
```

In the third table there is no primary key. So it gives an error while running. Here is the error message -

> System.Data.Edm.EdmEntityType: :
>   EntityType 'User_role' has no key
>   defined. Define the key for this
>   EntityType.
>   System.Data.Edm.EdmEntitySet:
>   EntityType: The EntitySet User_roles
>   is based on type User_role that has no
>   keys defined.

Why its is happening? Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If think you are trying to model many-to-many relation between user and role. In such case your model is completely wrong.

Use this  instead:

```
public partial class App_user
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string email_address { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
    public int user_type { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}

public partial class Role
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

This will create many-to-many automatically and you will not need to bother with junction table. If you need to expose junction table you must use this:

```
public partial class App_user
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string email_address { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
    public int user_type { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User_Role> UserRoles { get; set; }
}

public partial class Role
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User_Role> UserRoles { get; set; }
}

public partial class User_role
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("App_user"), Column(Order = 0)]
    public int user_id { get; set; }
    [Key, ForeignKey("Role"), Column(Order = 1)]
    public int role_id { get; set; }
    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
    public virtual App_user App_user { get; set; }
}
```

Exposing junction table is meaningless if you don't need additional properties in it.

To your error - each entity in Entity framework must have primary key defined.

Comment: [Key, ForeignKey("App_user"), Column(Order = 0)] - 
What is the namespace to use with it?

Comment: System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations (it has also separate assembly).

Comment: @LadislavMrnka, I do not seem to apply `[Key, ForeignKey("App_user"), Column(Order = 0)]`, only [Key] is available, what am I missing ?  Thanks.

Comment: @autrevo: Make sure you are referencing EntityFramework.dll. .NET 4.0 does not contain those annotations directly (.NET 4.5 does).

Comment: the `ForeignKey("")` is not really necessary.

Answer (score 19):

You can simply do like this:

```
public partial class User_role
{
    [Key]
    public int user_id { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public int role_id { get; set; }
    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
    public virtual App_user App_user { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: wouldn't that make user_id key? What if user is in many roles?

Comment: what about something like that?

Comment: @YngveB.Nilsen how do you add the [Key] Property ? I refered System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotation. But it only shows [foreignkey] is [key] under a diferent directory ?

Comment: @omachu23 back in 2011 (when this answer was written) it was in System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotation, but what it is today is a different question :)

Answer (score 1):

Because I used an ADO.net Entiry Data Model with automated generated code I didn't want to change the Model classes so I changed the WebApiConfig.cs to define the keys of the underlying models:

```
ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
EntitySetConfiguration<Registration> EntitySetConfiguration_Registration = builder.EntitySet<Registration>("Registration");
EntitySetConfiguration<Lead> EntitySetConfiguration_Lead = builder.EntitySet<Lead>("Lead");
EntitySetConfiguration<Session> EntitySetConfiguration_Session = builder.EntitySet<Session>("Session");
EntitySetConfiguration_Registration.EntityType.HasKey(p => p.Registration_Id);
EntitySetConfiguration_Lead.EntityType.HasKey(p => p.Lead_Id);
EntitySetConfiguration_Session.EntityType.HasKey(p => p.Session_Id);
config.Routes.MapODataRoute("odata", "odata", builder.GetEdmModel());
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure you are using (using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;)

just add the keyword [Key] at the top of the data field in the Model