# .NET Error: Sequence contains more than one matching element

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, orm

I’m using .NET Entity Framework and every time I’m trying to access db data I get an error:

```
public async Task<List<model>> getModel()
{
    return await dbContext.ModelTable.ToListAysnc()
}
```

Comment: There is nothing here what should result in this error directly. This error usually happens when one of `Single` method is called and there are multiple entries in the result.

Comment: But there is another possible reason -  check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69236321/entity-framework-sequence-contains-more-than-one-matching-element/69237308#69237308). In short - you need to update EF Core packages to corresponding latest versions.