# Entity Framework 4.1 dont generate Id when save data

Tags: c#, .net, database, entity-framework

I'm trying to do something simple, but this dont work in EF 4.1,it does in EF 6, but I cant update version because I need this application in an old server and doesnt support it.

This is my code:

```
               chat = new Chat()
                        {
                            AdminId = 99
                        };

                        db.Chat.Add(chat);
                        db.SaveChanges();

                var cp = new List<ChatPeople>();
                        foreach (int user in usersids)
                        {
                            cp.Add(new ChatPeople
                            {
                                ChatId = chat.Id,
                                UserId = user
                            });
                        }
                        cp.ForEach(c => db.ChatPeople.Add(c));
```

and this is the model:

```
[Table("CHATS", Schema = "SCHEMA")]
    public class Chat
    {     

        [Column("ID")]
        public decimal Id { get; set; }       

        [Column("ADMINID")]
        public decimal AdminId { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ChatPeople> ChatPeople { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ChatHistory> ChatHistory { get; set; }
    }
```

(I need decimal Id because int dont work in Oracle.)

My problem is when I save `Chat`, this dont return the current Id of this registry in database and when in ChatPeople try to do this  `ChatId = chat.Id,` I dont have the value. In DB `Chat` are saving ok with `AdminId = 99` and `Id = (Autonumeric-Identity)`

What can I do to get Id of registry that are being saved?

Comment: possible duplicate of [EF6 CodeFirst My \[Key\] Id Column is not auto-incrementing as an identity column should](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23147479/ef6-codefirst-my-key-id-column-is-not-auto-incrementing-as-an-identity-column)

Comment: Maybe, I didn't find an answer until now and I found my answer  here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14612813/entity-framework-code-first-using-one-column-as-primary-key-and-another-as-auto  I thought this problem was for EF version

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the attribute [Key] above your ID This should set it as the primary key for the table that's generated by EF.

```
    [Key]
    [Column("ID")]
    public decimal Id { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks John Id had Key attribute, only I need put this other attribute  [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] and works ok.

Answer (score 0):

I need put this other attribute  `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` and works ok.

Answer in this post: 
[Entity Framework Code First Using One column as Primary Key and another as Auto Increment Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14612813/entity-framework-code-first-using-one-column-as-primary-key-and-another-as-auto)

Finally:

```
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Column("ID")]
        public decimal Id { get; set; }
```