# Cannot insert duplicate key row in object

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

The first time I add a migration my seeding works. However, if I run it again I get the exception

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot insert duplicate key row in
>   object 'dbo.Attributes' with unique index 'IX_AttributeName'. The
>   duplicate key value is (State).

From my understanding, AddOrUpdate should not add if the entity already exists. Am I misunderstanding?

**Attribute Entity**

```
 public class Attribute
    {
        public Attribute()
        {
            IsList = false;
        }

        public int AttributeId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(255)]
        [Index("IX_AttributeName",1,IsUnique = true)]
        public string AttributeName { get; set; }
        public bool IsPHI { get; set; }
        public bool IsList { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<AttributeTerm> AttributeListTerms { get; set; }

    }
```

**Portion of Seeding class (updated after Gusman's advice)**

```
 public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        }

        protected override void Seed(GBARDbContext context)
        {

            var attributes = new[]
            {
            new Attribute {AttributeId = 2, AttributeName = "First Name"},
            new Attribute {AttributeId = 3, AttributeName = "Last Name"},
            new Attribute {AttributeId = 4, AttributeName = "Middle Name"},
            new Attribute {AttributeId = 5, AttributeName = "Street"},
            new Attribute {AttributeId = 1, AttributeName = "State", IsList = true},
            };

           context.Attributes.AddOrUpdate(a => a.AttributeId, attributes);
           context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Could be a race condition if  `Seed`  is called from different threads at the same time.

Comment: If I recall it right the update will only update a record according to it's primary key, not by secondary indexes.

Comment: @Gusman I tried that at first and when that didn't work I read this https://stackoverflow.com/a/15413951/5004521, and realized it shouldn't be an identity column as it is auto-generated/incremented

Comment: The sample code works for me.

Comment: before run this code again please check, probably you already have the same data on the database, and now you are trying insert the same data. As @Gusman mentioned, this code will never try to update, it will always try to insert data

Comment: I do have the same data in the database, but I thought AddOrUpdate will avoid duplicates. I changed it to be with the primary key but still does now work

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by listening to Gusman and Alex S's advice of using the primary key to seed with. I had to delete all data and reset the identity counter first for the `Attribute` table and its depending `AttributeTerm` table

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('Attributes', RESEED, 0)
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('AttributeTerms', RESEED, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two columns that are unique right? The AttributeId and the AttributeName, so in the AddOrUpdate you should set this. Here's the solution:

```
context.Attributes.AddOrUpdate(a => new { a.AttributeId , a.AttributeName} , attributes);
context.SaveChanges();
```