# Entity Framework Code First Map (Linked) Table?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

I'm working with the EF code first approach and want to add a link (map) table. I am working off the below example and get the following error:

```
System.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'EmployeeDepartmentLink' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
```

Problem is I dont want a key on this table it just maps the two tables together:

```
public class Employee
{
    [Key()]
    public int EmployeeID;
    public string Name;
}

public class Department
{
    [Key()]
    public int DepartmentID;
    public string Name;
}

public class EmployeeDepartmentLink
{
    public int EmployeeID;
    public int DepartmentID;
}
```

I have tried a variety of things like adding the "[Key()]" attribute but it doesn't make sense for it to be used, and which field do I add it to? I am wondering if this sort of table model is even supported?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5482670/entity-framework-code-first-define-the-key-for-this-entitytype

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `M:M relationship` you have to create your join (link) class is as below.

```
public class EmployeeDepartmentLink
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int EmployeeID;

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int DepartmentID;

}
```

For more information check [**Create code first, many to many**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050404/create-code-first-many-to-many-with-additional-fields-in-association-table)

I hope this will help to you.

Comment: Just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 15):

You are trying to make a "Many to Many" mapping.

To perform this, write this code:

```
public class Employee
{
    [Key]
    public int EmployeeId;
    public string Name;
    public List<Department> Departments { get; set; }

    public Employee()
    {
        this.Departments = new List<Department>();
    }
}

public class Department
{
    [Key]
    public int DepartmentId;
    public string Name;

    public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }

    public Department()
    {
        this.Employees = new List<Employee>();
    }
}
```

then, in your `DbContext`:

```
public class YourContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }

    public YourContext() : base("MyDb")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Department>().
            HasMany(c => c.Employees).
            WithMany(p => p.Departments).
            Map(
                m =>
                {
                    m.MapLeftKey("DepartmentId");
                    m.MapRightKey("EmployeeId");
                    m.ToTable("DepartmentEmployees");
                });
    }
}
```

Comment: I knew it would be possible in the fluent API without creating a third object to represent the mapping table.