# Link table in EntityFramework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, postgresql

I'm using PostGre for my RoleProvider.
That my DbContext.

```cs
public class MembershipDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<RoleUser> RoleUsers { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("Users");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Role>().ToTable("Roles");
        modelBuilder.Entity<RoleUser>().ToTable("RoleUser");
    }
}
```

And models:

```cs
public class User
{
    public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }

    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string PasswordSalt { get; set; }
}

public class Role
{
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }

    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class RoleUser
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Role"), Column(Order = 0)]
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    [Key, ForeignKey("User"), Column(Order = 1)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

Problem sample:

```cs
    var dbContext = new MembershipDbContext();

    var users = dbContext.Users.ToList();
    var roles = dbContext.Roles.ToList();

    //it says: "ERROR: 42P01: relation "dbo.RoleUser1" not exist"
    var rolesOfFirstUser = users[0].Roles;//not working 
    var usersOfFirstRole = roles[0].Users;//not working

    var roleUsers = dbContext.RoleUsers.ToList();//all links works perfect
```

What should I do to make it work?
[This answer fixes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14442001/2084457) it, but I have no idea where is EF creates "RoleUsers" link table. I need it.

p.s. Sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should actually make those collections (on both files) point to RoleUser, i.e. the following:

`public virtual ICollection<RoleUser> RoleUsers {get;set;}`

Comment: Thank you. I did that, but is it really impossible to do direct access dbContext.Users.Roles (with RoleUsers table) instead of dbContext.Users.RoleUsers.Roles (but without RoleUsers table)?

Comment: I believe it is, and if you think about it, it makes sense why: Users to Roles is a Many-to-Many, thus requiring a Link table. In order for you to get to a User's roles you would need to go through that link table (just think about how you would write a SQL query to get it).